# topaths ending with at end

Tags: tikz-pgf, draw

The following code displays the problem

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{circuits}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[circuit]
    \draw (0,0) to [circuit handle symbol={draw,shape=rectangle,at start}] (0,3);
    \draw (1,3) to [circuit handle symbol={draw,shape=rectangle,at end}] (1,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This, compiled with expected output before upgrading to latest version of pgf. The two lines ending in a small rectangle should be identical, but in the case of `at end` it seems that the rectangle is rotated and thus moving the paths end point from the expected end point.

What I would like now is to control this behavior using a parameter in my tikzets since I ofcourse have tons of them for my drawings library.

[image]

Comment: Looks like a bug to me. Make a bug report.

Comment: I've never reported bugs before. But I've tried now. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 1):

You are right; there is a problem when the node is added at `pos=1` (and only then).  It seems that the anchoring point (with respect to the node) is at `west` all the time.

I see two ways to handle the situation: either using `anchor=south`, or whatever is convenient in the case at hand, or using `pos=.999`.  I would prefer the latter.

An example.[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{circuits}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[circuit,
  every node/.style={scale=.7},
  every label/.style={text=black, scale=.9}]
  \draw[gray, very thin, dashed] (-2, -1) grid (7, 5);
  \draw[thick]
  (-2, 0) node[fill=white] {start level} -- +(1.5, 0)
  (-2, 4) node[fill=white] {end level} -- +(1.5, 0);
  
  \draw[blue, thick] (0, 0) to [
  circuit handle symbol={draw, shape=rectangle, fill=yellow, at start},
  circuit handle symbol={draw, shape=rectangle, pos=.7},
  circuit handle symbol={draw, shape=rectangle, at end}
  ] +(2, 4);

  \draw[red, thick] (2, 0) to [
  circuit handle symbol={draw, shape=rectangle, fill=yellow, at start},
  circuit handle symbol={draw, shape=rectangle, pos=.7},
  circuit handle symbol={%
    draw, shape=rectangle, at end, anchor=south,
    label={[above]80:{with anchor=south}}
  }] +(2, 4);
  
  \draw[red, thick] (4, 0) to [
  circuit handle symbol={draw, shape=rectangle, fill=yellow, at start},
  circuit handle symbol={draw, shape=rectangle, pos=.7},
  circuit handle symbol={%
    draw, shape=rectangle, pos=.9999,
    label={[above right, text width=5em]90:with pos=.9999}
  }] +(2, 4);  
\end{tikzpicture}  

\end{document}
```